# ?&price=10-100 Has no effect

Tags: php, price, catalog, filter

I'm trying to filter my products using the method in the title, but when I run it, nothing happens.

Is this not the way to filter products by price?

Answer (score 0):

This should be it. Is your price set as filterable? Why don't you use the price filter handles to determine the url?

Comment: Yes price is set to filterable. I have a feeling that it's an extension doing it but I don't know which one :S
Could that be a possibility? What's the best way of troubleshooting this ?

Comment: There is some extensions influencing the URL structure. (Especially SEO-Layered Navigation Extensions.) Got to `/app/etc/modules/mysuspisciousExtension.xml`, open it and set `<active>false</active`. As a result the extension is deactivated and things should work as per default. (Don't forget to clear caches!)

Where is your price filter? Regular themes have that in the filter navigation, so you could get the URL from there.

Comment: Awesome thanks. The one I suspected wasn't that one so I'll have to go through them all :/

Comment: If your questions is answered, please "accept" the question by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: I don't think it has worked. Doing so breaks the site and I have to re-enable the modules. I don't think it's theme related either as I've tried on a different theme.